# How to create styled boxes on a webpage in where I can add graphs,gaugs,numbers?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I'm creating a 1 page dashboard that will run fullscreen on a monitor on which I want to display some graphs. I made the graphs already all I need now is a proper template for the page. I was thinking something like this [image]

I really dig the look but I'm clueless on how to make something like this using presumably css/js. Especially the lines in the background and a titlebox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to code all of the man div-containers including your graphs and data-visuals. For that, a css-framework could help you managing the different views for all devices (http://getbootstrap.com/).

Later on, you could add inner divs for the title box and the background. Also get yourself some inspiration. For example: this is the admin-theme I am using for my actual project: http://admindesigns.com/framework/dashboard.html

After digging into that, you may ask some deeper questions about styling your Dashboard, so it's easier for us to respond to an actual problem ;)

Cheers,
Chris

Comment: Thanks Chris, got a question though. It's only going to run on one single laptop, so no support needed for multiple devices. Is it really useful to use bootstrap in this case?

Comment: Hey Kenan, 
It's not necessary to use a framework like bootstrap if you use your dashboard on only one single device where the measures aren't changing, but it can happen, that your buying a bigger screen or change your screen-resolution - so I recommend to use percentage-driven widths in css.
A css framework helps you with that but it can be sometimes a little bit too heavy for small projects.

Nevertheless: If you regularly built websites you will get in contact with css-frameworks because they really help improving your workflow.  

Finally, the choice is up to you :)